# Changing Hosts, Can I forward Traffic from A records to another ip?

Tags: a-record

We have a lot of 3rd party sites on ip1, who have their own A records to update.

We wish to move to a new host, and use ip2, and while we can update DNS to ip2 on things we control, we have 100 or so folks who will have downtime while they figure it out.

.. is there a way for Apache or Nginx to receive a request for DomainA, and create a redirect or tunnel to newserver to serve the resources?

I am fine if it is slow(er), the key is uptime.

Ive seen mod proxy, etc, but is this the recommended solution, or is there a more performant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the reverse proxy is the ideal way. If the distance between the new server and the old server isn't great, the change in response time is quite minimal.

As you mentioned, mod_proxy is one possible solution if you're using apache. Nginx has reverse proxy built in and doesn't need any further mods.

If nginx will be your solution, the setup will look like so:

```
upstream newserver {
  server YourNewIpHere:port; # EDIT THIS
}

server {
  server_name domains that needs to be forwarded space delimited; # EDIT THIS
  listen 80;  # for http
  listen [::]:443; # for ssl

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; # this passes the actual user IP to the new server
  proxy_set_header Host $host; # same for the host
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;

  location / {
    proxy_pass newserver;
  }
}
```

Official guide: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

and on the receiving nginx server, you'll need to set it so that the forwarded address is the real one. Syntax for it looks like so:

```
set_real_ip_from  IpOfOldServer; # EDIT THIS
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

A similar setup needs to be done if you're using mod_proxy for apache. Docs for mod_proxy: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html